# How to find solution of ODE system by Liouville formula

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Consider a linear ODE system
$$\mathbf{y}'=A(x)\mathbf{y}$$
defined on an interval $I$ and $A(x)\mathbf{y}$ satisfying Lipschitz condition for $\mathbf{y}$.
As presented in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_formula) (the application part), if $A(x)$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix and we have already known a solution, say $\mathbf{y_0}$, then we can use Liouville formula to determine a fundamental solution matrix.

**My question**: If $A(x)$ is $3 \times 3$, is there any similar result? Of course two linearly independent solutions $\mathbf{y_1}$ and $\mathbf{y_2}$ can generate a fundamental solution matrix. But can we yield a fundamental solution matrix by **knowing only one solution**? If not, can we restrict some of the conditions to make it happen? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will notice in that Wikipedia page, it doesn't say a "$2 \times 2$" matrix. It says "a square matrix of dimension $n$", that is, an $n \times n$ matrix. $n$ can be any positive integer value, including $3$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Then how can I prove the case for $n \ge 3$?  Could you give me some references or hint?

Comment: Yes. Go read the wikipedia page you yourself linked to. Scroll down to where it says "proof". TA DA! There it is.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I think you misunderstood my question. I’m not asking how to prove Liouville’s formula or does it exist when $n \ge 3$. I’m asking how to find solutions by Liouville’s formula.